# mutating table when writing a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have been bogged in this problem for quite a long time....Can anyone help me out?
Here is the thing I want to implement:
I have a table A, A has attributes: id, count, total. Here I am required to implement such a trigger: IF the count in table A is updated, the trigger will set the total to 1.

My initial code is like this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_A AFTER UPDATE OF count ON A
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    UPDATE A SET total = 1 WHERE id = :new.id;
    END;
    /
```

The problem with this is the mutating table. When the table is updated, the table will be locked. I searched for the answers, I tried pragma autonomous_transaction, but I got an invalid trigger specification error. And there are other comments saying that we should try to use a combination of triggers to do this....I can't figure out how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `id` is the primary key, you don't want to `UPDATE` the table.  You just want to set `:new.total`.  You'll also need to do this in a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger not an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tri_A 
  BEFORE UPDATE OF count ON A
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.total := 1;
END;
```

Comment: You are right! Thank you so much!!!I can't believe that I have wasted so much time on the wrong direction.......